# simplexml and xpath - echoing a node?

Tags: php, simplexml

I select a node from a simplexml-Object by `xpath`:

```
$x="<root>
    <person>
    <name>Julie</name>
    <age>37</age>   
    <rating>5</rating>
    </person>
    <person>
    <name>Greta</name>
    <age>56</age>
    <rating>7</rating>
    </person>
    <person>
    <name>Kerstin</name>
    <age>38</age>
    <rating>10</rating>
    </person>   
</root>";

$xml = simplexml_load_string($x);

$person = $xml->xpath("//person[name='Greta']");

foreach ($person[0] as $k => $v) 
    echo "$k => $v<br />";
```

This is outputting as expected...

```
name => Greta<br />age => 56<br />rating => 7<br />
```

Then I do...

```
echo $person[0]['age'];
```

Output:

right, nothing! Why?

Try it live @ http://3v4l.org/Voalu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SimpleXML](http://php.net/SimpleXML) uses object properties, not array members, for child nodes (array members are used for accessing node attributes).  The following expression will get you the age:

```
echo $person[0]->age;
```

If the XML had looked like the following, your code would have worked:

```
<root>
    <person age="37">
       <name>Julie</name>
       <rating>5</rating>
    </person>
    ...
```